# ggplot geom_bar() fill not coloring bars on plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, kaggle

Using the fill argument on geom_bar is not coloring the bars on my plot. I'm using the train.csv from the titanic data set [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data).

```
passengers <- read.csv('../input/train.csv')
```

I have tried moving the fill outside of the aes(), tried moving the aes up to the ggplot() function.

This is the code I'm using on the Titanic Data set

```
ggplot(data = passengers) + 
    geom_bar(mapping = aes(x=Survived, fill = Pclass))
```

[image]

This is the code I'm using as a template which works fine on the ggplot built in diamonds data.

```
ggplot(data = diamonds) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = cut, fill = cut))
```

[image]

I just keep getting grey bars with the geom_bar for Survived using Pclass as the fill.

Comment: It's going to be hard for anyone to help without access to `passengers`, your data frame of however you've reorganized the Titanic data set.

Comment: DOH! Sorry about that. Have edited with the link to the data set and which file I read into the dataframe.

Comment: Please add data directly to your question, not as a link.

Comment: is Pclass numeric? if so, try throwing an `as.character()` around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is doing the trick for me:

```
ggplot(data = passengers) + 
   geom_bar(mapping = aes(x=Survived, fill = as.character(Pclass)))
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know why this is? I checked typeof(diamonds$cut) and typeof(titanic$Pclass). Both are integers. What would cause it to work on one and not the other?

Comment: @Michael - using `str()` - cut is showing up as an ordered factor. i'm afraid i'm not positive why ordered factors are treated as ints with respect to `typeof()`.

Comment: Tried with as.factor() and that works as well. Guess I'll take another look at ?geom_bar() and ggplot2-specs. Don't see anything explicitly stating it needs to be a factor or character. Just something I'll have to keep in mind. Thank you kind sir!

Answer (score 0):

You can try as.factor()

```
ggplot(data = passengers) + 
geom_bar(mapping = aes(x=Survived, fill = as.factor(passengers$Pclass)))
```

Probably your variables is not factor